# The Tor network has been infiltrated by hackers?

Tags: tor-network

Apparently, the Tor network was infiltrated by hackers last year (https://www.techradar.com/news/tor-browser-is-wrestling-with-a-major-security-problem). According to the article, a group of hackers started operating malicious servers in the tor network. I read this today (I'm a new Tor user) and I was concerned.

What's the status on this security issue? How has the Tor project been doing in stopping these hackers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the Tor Project:

https://blog.torproject.org/bad-exit-relays-may-june-2020

There are two separate issues (1) Exit operators are performing SSL stripping, and (2) there are sybil attacks where malicious parties are running many Tor relays.

SSL stripping is not something unique to Tor, and on the Internet it's up to the client and server to make sure they encrypt their communication properly. Since many websites don't follow best practices like using HSTS, and users don't always check to make sure they're using HTTPS, the Tor Browser might support an HTTPS-only mode sometime in the future that would prevent SSL stripping.

Preventing malicious relays from joining the network is a difficult problem, but the Tor Project does monitor the network to try to identify malicious relays. The difficulty is that there's usually not a clear sign that a relay is behaving maliciously, or it may try to hide its behaviour. There may also be timing patterns to look for (for example if many relays joined the network at the same time, or all updated at the same time), but this is easy for an attacker to work around.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up for me.